# KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' - No idea what is wrong

Tags: key, azure-keyvault

App service and key vault are under same resources.

App has identity set to On

Access policy: https://i.gyazo.com/70b450fbe78a3693afa0a59c16b9e9e4.png

App also is contributor to key vault

````
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync(string vaultBaseUrl, Nullable<int> maxresults, Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretsAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, string vaultBaseUrl, Nullable<int> maxresults, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList<IConfigurationProvider> providers)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
FindEnBar.Program.Main(string[] args) in Program.cs ```
````

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it works now. Idk why.